# density of fractions with prime numerator and denominator

Tags: prime-numbers

Let S = the set of proper fractions p/q where p and q are prime.

Is S dense in the interval [0,1] ?

That is to say if L is the limit points of S does S Union L = [0,1] ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, $S$ is dense in $[0,1]$.  This follows easily from fact that

> for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_\epsilon$ such that the interval $[x,(1+\epsilon)x]$ contains a prime for all $x > N_\epsilon$

which in turn follows from the Prime Number Theorem.